# EF6 don't use pre-generated views

Tags: c#, entity-framework, view, edmgen

I've pregenerated views using this instruction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896240(v=vs.100).aspx
and already have `Model.Views.cs` file in my project with my context and all entities.

The problem is that these views are not used at run-time. `ViewsForBaseEntitySets2F2...` class never gets initialized and performance is still poor.

How to force EF to use pre-generated views?

If it must use it by default (looking for `EntityViewGenerationAttribute` on assembly) then what I have done wrong and how to diagnose that?

**UPD**
I've just found `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.MappingViews` namespace which is confusing.

Also, there are several unanswered questions:

[Entity Framework Pre-Generated View on Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927314/entity-framework-pre-generated-view-on-assembly)

[ADO.NET Entity Framework - Pre-Generate Views -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149290/ado-net-entity-framework-pre-generate-views)

[How do Entity Framework pre-compiled views get loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999896/how-do-entity-framework-pre-compiled-views-get-loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article which is not outdated: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469601.aspx

It answers all questions.