# Using pre-generated views with DevForce EDMX

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, devforce

I am using Entity Framework Tools 6 to pre-generate views for my EDMX model. Everything looks great and compiles, however I don't see actual difference. Breakpoints anywhere in views file doesn't get hit.

I also tried to change model and it should not work without re-generating views but it does. That makes me think those views is not getting used and I'm not sure why.

I cross-checked with article mentioned here: [EF6 don't use pre-generated views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529039/ef6-dont-use-pre-generated-views) but all looks good.

EDIT: Tried the same with another non-DevForce EDMX and it works as expected. So, it's a question on how to enable those pre-generated views for DevForce context

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related but [this page](http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/query-performance) has this note: `Use of EDMGen pre-generated views was made obsolete in EF 6.  The newer approach, used by the EF Power Tools, requires that a DbContext is used; because of this, pre-generated views cannot be used with a DevForce "database first" model`
We have been considering a move to EF6 and that sentence certainly scared me a bit.